# Android setNextFocusDown on programatically created view

Tags: android, layout, focus

My layout contains a `LinearLayout` which contains, when inflated, a single button.

After inflation, 3 more views are added programmatically and what I want to be able to do is set the `nextFocusDown` of the initial button to the first created view in my loop, like so:

```
ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(btnBack);

forV(x=0;x<=45;x++) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_great_item, null);

    // what I really want to be able to do here is something like
    // if(x==0) btnBack.setNextFocusDown(l);
    // but here there only exists the method setNextFocusDownId - I can't pass a view directly to the function.

    l.setFocusable(true);
    l.setClickable(true);

    ...

    l.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        ...
    });

    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       ...
    });

   mybaseview.addView(l)
}
```

The problem being, as per the comments, there doesn't seem to be a method `setNextFocusDown(View)` - so I can't figure out a way to achieve this, other than nesting the programmatically created views in a dummy parent layout - but I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `values/ids.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="your_custom_id" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Than change your code like this:

```
ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(btnBack);

for(x=0;x<=45;x++) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_great_item, null);

    if (x==0) {
        l.setId(R.id.your_custom_id);
        btnBack.setNextFocusDown(R.id.your_custom_id);
    }

    l.setFocusable(true);
    l.setClickable(true);

    ...

    l.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        ...
    });

    l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       ...
    });

   mybaseview.addView(l)
}
```